# FastAPI: Retrieve the endpoint for jinja2 `url_for` to give a jump link

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, fastapi

### Function description

In flask this code:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return ...
```

or

```py
foo_router = Blueprint('foo', __name__)
@foo_router.route('/')
def index():
    return ...

app.register_blueprint(foo_router, url_prefix='/api')
```

These ways you are able to use `url_for('index')` to retrieve url like `https://hostname:8080/`

or use `url_for('foo.index')` to retrive url like `https://hostname:8080/api/foo`

### Desired function

Use `url_for` for jump link in `fastapi` like `flask`

### Additional context

I have found a trick to do the implement

create `url_naming.py` and add the code below

```py
from starlette.routing import Mount, Route

from .routers.foo.endpoints.area import index as foo_area_index

foo_router_for = Mount('/', routes=[
    Route('/area', foo_area_index, name='foo_area.index'),
])
```

and in your `main.py` add

```py
from .url_naming import foo_router_for

app.add_route('/foo', foo_router_for, name='foo_area.index')
```

In the codeblocks, I define `name` twice because which `name` I defined in a `Route` model cannot be detected by FastAPI, or it is overridden by FastAPI, and **this impl make no sense** because it is required to write down the real router name rather than the endpoint function name.

Despite that, what if I'd like to name my router in one file, which do not make effect on `main.py`?

Answer (score 7):

I solve the problem with the following solution.

Just to name your handle function (endpoint) and the name can be normally used by `url_for`.

```py
router = APIRouter(prefix='/api')

@router.get('/foo')
async def api_foo():
    return ...
```

This way you can retrieve the url `http://hostname:8080/api/foo/` using `url_for('api_foo')`.

I guess this is because all the handle functions in FastAPI are named in the same space, and if they are named in FastAPI repeatedly, no error will be reported.

Comment: Thank you very much. But How did you know this --> "this is because all the handle functions in FastAPI are named in the same space". Is this mentioned in docs?